# Checking whether focus is set to excel cell

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, vba

I am working on VSTO Project. I need to detect the input focus in Excel vsto project.

I want to check whether focus is on excel cell or it is on other excel component like find dialog, document action pane or any other excel built-in dialog.

Is this possible to detect?

[image: Please refer screen shot]

As shown in screen shot, I want to know whether input focus is set to excel cell or not?

Comment: Can I ask why you need to do this?

Comment: @JMK I want to restrict my paste special code to execute when input focus is not on excel cell.

Comment: Maybe `Excel.Worksheet.ActiveCell=null` or `Excel.ActiveCell=null`.

Comment: @RoadBump : whether input focus is on excel cell or not excel.activecell returns active cell. :(

Comment: excel always has the object `Activecell` so I don't think the answer will lie there `Activecell.address` will always return a value whether a dialog box has the focus or not. Rather than trying to find what has the focus are you not able to fortc it to focus on a particular cell and then work from there?

Comment: @whytheq : No I can not do like that because functionality is depends on the focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get the title of the active window (vba)

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetActiveWindow Lib "User32.dll" () As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long

Function ActiveWindowName()
Dim hWnd As Long
Dim lngRet As Long
Dim strText As String

hWnd = GetActiveWindow()
strText = String(100, Chr(0))
lngRet = GetWindowText(hWnd, strText, 100)
ActiveWindowName=strText
End Function
```

It will return the title on the active window, but I assume a length of 100 characters will be enough.

This code should give a function that returns the current title, and correctly adjust for length. (I currently do not have c# installed, so I can't test this):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

public static string GetActiveWindowText()
{
    IntPtr hWnd = GetActiveWindow();  
    // Allocate correct string length first
    int length = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length + 1);
    GetWindowText(hWnd, sb, sb.Capacity);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

You should then be able to test the string to see what it contains. In the VBA example, entering `=ActiveWindowName()` into **A1** returns `Microsoft Excel - Book1`

Comment: In your C# code the line `intPtr hWind = GetActiveWindow();` should be `IntPtr hWnd = GetActiveWindow();` but otherwise I can confirm that it seems to work. It returned the correct window name for a few combinations I tried.

Comment: @SidHolland I updated the answer.  Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this :

```
private bool CheckInputisinExcelCell()
{
    Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBarControl cmdEdited;
    cmdEdited=YourExcelApplicationobject.CommandBars.FindControl(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, 23, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
    return cmdEdited.Enabled;
}
```

Comment: Can you debug the code and make sure that YourExcelApplicationobject is of type ExcelApplication, if not than you need to get hold of your ExcelApplication from your code

Comment: My application object is typeof ExcelApplication only but the thing is in both case 1. If input focus is on excel cell or 2. input focus is on document action pane cmdEdit.Enabled is true.

Comment: What about `Activecell.Select` before paste? That should bring the focus back to the sheet?

Comment: @JüriRuut : But i want to check whether focus is on selected cell or not?

Comment: I fiddled around a little bit: `Esc` key takes the focus from Help/Document pane to the spreadsheet.

Comment: In VBA:
`Application.CommandBars("Task Pane").Enabled = False`